# Building iPhone apps through Corona: How do I create a fake signing identity and provision file?

Tags: provisioning, ios-provisioning, coronasdk, provisioning-profile

I'm using Corona to create a game but to build the app for iOS I need to specify in Corona which provisioning profile to use (which I have to copy to their certain folder).

They state that either a development or adhoc provisioning profile can work.

How do I create a fake ad hoc provisioning profile?

I tried using and old mobileprovision.mobileprovision file that I had but it obviously didn't work because Corona stated that the certficate was not installed.

Here is a link of the whole process to setup for building for iOS (legal):

http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/building-devices-iphoneipad

I am running Mac OSX 10.6.6 with xCode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3.

Answer (score 3):

In short: you can’t. Provisioning profiles are part of the code-signing process; non-jailbroken iOS devices will not run code that has not been cryptographically signed with a valid provisioning profile.

To run your code on a device, you either need to jailbreak it (so it’ll accept non-Apple-signed code) or cough up the $99/year to become a member of the iOS developer program (so you can give your code a valid signature). Only the latter option will allow you to then submit your app to the App Store, and it’s a lot less hassle, so you’re probably best off just going with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can test Corona apps in the simulator for free, but you have to be a licensed developer in order to deploy to device.

Comment: And to clarify, this is an Apple-imposed limitation, not a Corona one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bundling your own IPA file, but I think the IPA will only transfer if the iDevice is jailbroken.  This process worked for me on my jailbroken iPhone.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171462/708807

Answer (score 0):

This is a fake Hoc provisioning profile http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/step2/Exporting-the-App/

Comment: How to integrate it with corona ?