# No "Share" Button in Organizer

Tags: iphone, share, profile, provisioning

I have a valid developer profile. I could run and debug my app in iPhone. But, when I try archiving and sharing it, in Organizer I could see only validate and distribute. What should I do? If I had to change my provisioning profile by revoking it and creating it, how can I do it correctly. Because already I tried creating a new profile revoking the old one. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have upgraded to XCode 4.3, which removes the 'Share' button. You can use the 'Distribute' button, and just select an Ad Hoc build instead. More information at this question:

[How to make an IPA on XCode 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350972/how-to-make-an-ipa-on-xcode-4-3)

Comment: Thanks for you help. Saved hell lot of time.. :)