# How to build an ipa file from a xCode 5 project without developer membership?

Tags: xcode, iphone-5, ipa

I have appSync for iOS 7 in my Jailbroken device, so I'm only looking for export a project to a ipa.

Is this possible without having a developer membership from Apple as that costs 99 dollars per year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an IPA on XCode 4.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350972/how-to-make-an-ipa-on-xcode-4-3)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to install the application on your device for development testing without apple 
membership account.

Because to install the application you have to make a provisioning file and without membership account you can not make provisioning file

Thanks.